# Pre-Commit Error 'Cannot Find Module - npx-cli.js' When Using Husky

Tags: pre-commit-hook, husky

I am trying to run a pre-commit hook that checks check my style using husky and stylelint but when I try to commit a file GitKracken fails. The log reads as follows:

```
Error: Cannot find module C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT FOUND',
requireStack: []    
}
```

I am running npm version: *6.13.4* and node version: *12.14.1*. From my research npx is installed with npm in any versions over 5 or so already. I've also tried globally installing npx as well but it fails to install claiming file already exists.

I am sure it is a path problem or perhaps I am using husky incorrectly but figured I'd reach to to see if anyone knows why I'm having issues getting this to work. Thanks for any insights you may have.

**package.json**

```
// I've tested rand the stylelint command manually and it does check for stylelint errors

{
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "node ./node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js ./src/scss/**/*.scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very likely updated Husky from v4 to v7, look at [migration guide](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=husky-4-to-7-cli).